# odoo 13 : write() function updates on wrong record

Tags: python, odoo-13

I am new to odoo and I am working on the invoice reward splitting based on seller id.
When I split the reward discount in the sale order line the write() function updates on the wrong record may be due to tax id because the default functionality was splitting the reward discount in the sale order line with only tax.
Could anyone help me out to figure out the solution?

I actually inherited the  sales order with function _get_reward_values_discount to split  discount reward line based on the product seller

```
def _get_reward_values_discount(self,program):
        if program.discount_type == 'fixed_amount':
            taxes = program.discount_line_product_id.taxes_id
            if self.fiscal_position_id:
                taxes = self.fiscal_position_id.map_tax(taxes)
            return [{
                'name': _("Discount: ") + program.name,
                'product_id': program.discount_line_product_id.id,
                'price_unit': - self._get_reward_values_discount_fixed_amount(program),
                'product_uom_qty': 1.0,
                'product_uom': program.discount_line_product_id.uom_id.id,
                'is_reward_line': True,
                'tax_id': [(4, tax.id, False) for tax in taxes],
            }]
        reward_dict = {}
        lines = self._get_paid_order_lines()
        amount_total = sum(self._get_base_order_lines(program).mapped('price_subtotal'))
        if program.discount_apply_on == 'cheapest_product':
            line = self._get_cheapest_line()
            if line:
                discount_line_amount = min(line.price_reduce * (program.discount_percentage / 100), amount_total)
                if discount_line_amount:
                    taxes = line.tax_id
                    if self.fiscal_position_id:
                        taxes = self.fiscal_position_id.map_tax(taxes)

                    reward_dict[line.tax_id] = {
                        'name': _("Discount: ") + program.name,
                        'product_id': program.discount_line_product_id.id,
                        'price_unit': - discount_line_amount if discount_line_amount > 0 else 0,
                        'product_uom_qty': 1.0,
                        'product_uom': program.discount_line_product_id.uom_id.id,
                        'is_reward_line': True,
                        'tax_id': [(4, tax.id, False) for tax in taxes],
                    }
        elif program.discount_apply_on in ['specific_products', 'on_order']:
            if program.discount_apply_on == 'specific_products':
                # We should not exclude reward line that offer this product since we need to offer only the discount on the real paid product (regular product - free product)
                free_product_lines = self.env['sale.coupon.program'].search([('reward_type', '=', 'product'), ('reward_product_id', 'in', program.discount_specific_product_ids.ids)]).mapped('discount_line_product_id')
                lines = lines.filtered(lambda x: x.product_id in (program.discount_specific_product_ids | free_product_lines))

            # when processing lines we should not discount more than the order remaining total
            currently_discounted_amount = 0
            # _logger.info("**************************************************************************************************************************")
            for line in lines:
                discount_line_amount = min(self._get_reward_values_discount_percentage_per_line(program, line), amount_total - currently_discounted_amount)
                # _logger.info(line.name)
                # _logger.info(discount_line_amount)

                if discount_line_amount:


                    _select_seller_id= line.product_id._select_seller().name.id +"-"+ str(line.tax_id.id)

                    if _select_seller_id in reward_dict:
                        reward_dict[_select_seller_id]['price_unit'] -= discount_line_amount
                    else:
                        taxes = line.tax_id
                        if self.fiscal_position_id:
                            taxes = self.fiscal_position_id.map_tax(taxes)

                        tax_name = ""
                        if len(taxes) == 1:
                            tax_name = " - " + _("On product with following tax: ") + ', '.join(taxes.mapped('name'))
                        elif len(taxes) > 1:
                            tax_name = " - " + _("On product with following taxes: ") + ', '.join(taxes.mapped('name'))

                        reward_dict[_select_seller_id] = {
                            'name': _("Discount: ") + program.name + tax_name + line.product_id._select_seller().name.name + str(discount_line_amount if discount_line_amount > 0 else 0),
                            'product_id': program.discount_line_product_id.id,
                            'price_unit': - discount_line_amount if discount_line_amount > 0 else 0,
                            'product_uom_qty': 1.0,
                            'product_uom': program.discount_line_product_id.uom_id.id,
                            'is_reward_line': True,
                            'tax_id': [(4, tax.id, False) for tax in taxes],
                            'partner_vendor_id' : line.product_id._select_seller().name.id,
                        }
                        currently_discounted_amount += discount_line_amount
                        _logger.info(reward_dict)

            # _logger.info("**************************************************************************************************************************")
        # If there is a max amount for discount, we might have to limit some discount lines or completely remove some lines
        max_amount = program._compute_program_amount('discount_max_amount', self.currency_id)
        if max_amount > 0:
            amount_already_given = 0
            for val in list(reward_dict):
                amount_to_discount = amount_already_given + reward_dict[val]["price_unit"]
                if abs(amount_to_discount) > max_amount:
                    reward_dict[val]["price_unit"] = - (max_amount - abs(amount_already_given))
                    add_name = formatLang(self.env, max_amount, currency_obj=self.currency_id)
                    reward_dict[val]["name"] += "( " + _("limited to ") + add_name + ")"
                amount_already_given += reward_dict[val]["price_unit"]
                if reward_dict[val]["price_unit"] == 0:
                    del reward_dict[val]
        # _logger.info(reward_dict.values())
        return reward_dict.values()
```

Comment: Post some of your code

Comment: Also, next to posting code, check if the sale order line write is overwritten in another module as well. Maybe there is implicit logic going on.